# NuGet Package Manager: "No packages found" even though the package exists

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

After updating Visual Studio to 2015 Update 2 I kept getting a "No packages found" error in NuGet Package Manager, despite browsing/searching for packages that I knew existed and which could be added from the Package Manager Console.

This is frustrating as the NuGet site clearly shows the packages are available. As a workaround I can install them via the Package Manager Console - but the GUI just shows "No packages found".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As of VS2015 Update 2 the default and only feed installed is  MS-Curated "Microsoft and .NET", https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/

This feed is missing a LOT of commonly used packages.

You can resolve this by simply adding the "normal" NuGet feed with all packages:

1. Open Visual Studio 2015 as admin
2. Tools > Options
3. NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources
4. Click the green "add" icon, and add the following feed:

   NuGet: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Answer (score 16):

Here are the troubleshooting steps I would take when looking into this issue.

1. **Visual Studio Settings**

   - Make sure you are in the **BROWSE** section.
   - Click on the Package Source drop down to the right.

     - Make sure **nuget.org** is listed.

       - If nuget.org is not listed, add it.

         - Open **Tools** > **Options** (Options window will open)
         - Locate **NuGet Package Manager** > **Package Sources**
         - Under available sources, click the **+** icon.
         - Enter **NuGet.org** as the package name
         - Enter **https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json** as the package source.
         - Click the **OK** button to save changes.
     - ****IMPORTANT**** Choose **ALL** as your package source to search all sources.

[image]

2. **Connectivity & DNS**

   - **Make sure internet is connected**

     - **Open CMD**
     - **ping 8.8.8.8**

       - If this does not respond your internet is not connected
     - **ping api.nuget.org**

       - If this does not resolve to an IP, then you have a DNS issue.
     - **nslookup api.nuget.org 8.8.8.8**

       - This should list the same IP address as the ping (along with some other info), If it does not then you may have a DNS issue (some local ISP DNS servers are not very good). Try changing your internet connection's DNS server to 8.8.8.8 and trying again.
3. **Proxy Issue**

   - **Do you have Fiddler open?** This can interfere with your connection to the nuget repository. Try shutting it down.
   - **Did you set all .NET to run through a proxy?** This is a common step taken in troubleshooting if you need to see all requests coming in.

     - Open C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
     - Remove or comment out the proxy configuration

Proxy Config Section

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled = "true" useDefaultCredentials = "true">
<proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" 
proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was looking for a prerelease and forgot to check Include prerelease

Answer (score 5):

Another reason people may end up seeing "No package found" is that the UI defaults to "Installed" packages. **Simply switch to the "Browse" tab**, instead of the "Installed" tab.

[image]